# Multiple PHP/MYSQL WHERE statements, same action for each

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to get PHP to read my MYSQL db for transactions, divide them by "category" and print the total for each category.

Using a similar structure as the code below, how can I make it do all of the below for each category number. In my db, categories are a number 1-10.

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
<?php

$result = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(amount) AS value_sum FROM TRANSACTIONS where      category=2") 
or die(mysql_error());  

while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {

echo "<div class='col1'>"; 
echo round ($row['value_sum'], 2);
echo "</div>"; 
} 

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(amount) AS value_sum 
                         FROM TRANSACTIONS 
                     GROUP BY category");
```

Now you have a row per category.